# Magento 2: links between entities: best practices

Tags: magento2, repository, orm, repositories

I have a question regarding link between entities.
Consider that a car is linked to a brand. The car entity will have a *brand_Id* attribute.

Coming from the "Symfony universe", using the Doctrine ORM, the linked entities will be automatically generated and loaded if used.

```
echo $myCar->getBrand()->getName();
```

My question is : is there a way to do the same with Magento 2? Until now, I had to inject the linked entity repository and use lazy loading.

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        BrandRepositoryInterface $brandRepository,  
        ...
) {

    $this->brandRepository = $brandRepository;
    ... 
}

public function getBrand() {
    if($this->brand == null) {
        $this->brand = $this->brandRepository->getById($this->getBrandId());
    }

    return $this->brand;
}
```

Is there an alternative like in the Doctrine ORM? Or something else, a good MG2 practice for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an other way of doing this in Magento (I may be wrong).
Code wise there is an other way, but the principle is the same.
[Here is an example in the core](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Item.php#L288).
It'a about the order -> order item relation.
Order is a parent entity for the order item entity.
The method `getOrder` from the `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` class looks like this:

```
public function getOrder()
{
    if ($this->_order === null && ($orderId = $this->getOrderId())) {
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create();
        $order->load($orderId);
        $this->setOrder($order);
    }
    return $this->_order;
}
```

This means (you already know what it means but I'm adding it here anyway) that if the `_order` member is not set, get the order from the database based on the order id.
This example does not use repositories, it calls directly the deprecated method `load`.
I guess this is because the orders models did not get refactored yet to use repositories.
Anyway, the repository approach is better because the order object is memoized.
Calling this 2 times for 2 different order items that belong to the same order will result in touching the db only once if you use repositories.

Conclusion: You are doing it right (in my opinion).

**[Edit]**
A similar approach is taken for the [order->invoice](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php#L233) relation and other relations in the sales module.